# Combine SVG paths without stroke going through the middle

Tags: html, image, svg

I am trying to combine paths. I have `stroke: black;` in my css. The problem is that a stroke-line cuts through the path.

Is there any tool to combine these without this line, or is it possible to do it manually. I have tried to combine all them by just adding all d parameters together.

My paths:

```html
<path class="subarea" d="M66.959,395.521c0.397,0,3.182,0.244,3.712,0c0.531-0.24,1.859-0.481,2.257-0.602c0.398-0.119,1.326-1.209,1.592-0.604
                c0.265,0.604,1.459,2.41,1.724,2.893c0.265,0.484,1.99,3.137,2.122,3.619c0.133,0.484,1.991,3.738,2.124,4.342
                c0.131,0.605,0.927,1.328,0.794,1.93s-0.794,1.086-0.794,1.086s-1.726,2.533-2.124,3.014c-0.398,0.482-1.325,1.449-1.459,2.051
                c-0.132,0.602,0,2.049,0,2.653c0,0.604-0.132,1.81-0.398,2.533c-0.265,0.724-0.529,1.445-0.795,1.93
                c-0.266,0.481-1.193,1.085-1.592,1.567c-0.397,0.481-1.193,2.653-1.327,3.376c-0.132,0.725-1.325,4.946-1.325,5.427
                c0,0.481-0.53,3.134-0.53,3.618c0,0.48-0.267,2.292-0.267,2.652c0,0.361-0.662,0.603-1.061,0.723
                c-0.397,0.123-1.327,0.725-1.591,1.086c-0.266,0.362-1.061,1.207-1.593,1.57c-0.53,0.359-2.122,1.082-2.519,1.202
                c-0.398,0.123-0.663-1.202-0.663-1.202s-0.795-3.377-1.061-3.98c-0.266-0.604-0.796-2.051-1.326-2.292
                c-0.531-0.243-1.459-1.206-2.122-1.085c-0.663,0.12-1.99,0.239-2.52,0c-0.531-0.242-1.326-0.485-1.726-0.725
                c-0.397-0.241-1.856-1.086-2.255-1.327c-0.397-0.24-0.796-0.721-1.193-0.965c-0.397-0.241-1.857-1.685-2.389-1.928
                c-0.531-0.241-1.46-0.604-1.46-0.604s-2.387-0.604-2.917-0.604s-1.989-0.48-2.388-0.601c-0.396-0.123-2.255-0.605-2.651-0.845
                c-0.399-0.241-1.196-0.968-1.196-1.447c0-0.482-0.264-1.93-0.264-2.292s0-2.172,0-2.172s2.52-0.844,2.653-1.326
                c0.132-0.48,1.192-1.687,1.592-2.049c0.397-0.361,1.592-0.724,1.857-1.085c0.266-0.362,3.183-2.292,3.581-2.774
                c0.396-0.482,4.509-3.014,4.907-3.256s3.316-2.17,3.715-2.291c0.397-0.121,2.255-1.208,2.52-1.568
                c0.266-0.361,1.724-0.243,2.521-0.724c0.796-0.483,3.316-1.567,3.847-1.81c0.529-0.239,2.52-1.447,2.653-1.809
                c0.133-0.362-0.003-2.531-0.133-3.014C67.356,397.33,66.959,395.521,66.959,395.521z"></path>
```

```html
<path class="subarea" d="M20.796,450.1c-1.061-1.447-2.651-4.824-5.836-11.577c-3.184-6.753-1.062-18.329-3.715-21.708
                c-1.454-1.85-5.645-17.83-2.52-19.725c5.969-3.617,1.193,3.98,5.704,5.736c0,0,1.591,1.62,2.122,2.225
                c0.53,0.602,1.591,2.289,1.724,2.893c0.133,0.604-0.133,2.413-0.133,2.894c0,0.483,0.266,2.051,0.53,2.413s0.929,1.567,1.592,1.93
                c0.663,0.359,2.52,1.205,2.786,1.566c0.265,0.361,1.192,1.326,1.458,1.809c0.267,0.484,1.193,2.413,1.326,2.774
                c0.132,0.362,0.664,1.447,0.664,1.81s0.664,2.776,0.664,3.137c0,0.361,0.264,1.445,0.264,1.928c0,0.481,0.133,1.567-0.133,2.173
                c-0.265,0.601-0.928,2.652-0.928,3.012c0,0.361-0.266,1.569-0.266,2.052c0,0.479-0.399,1.569-0.399,2.049c0,0.482,0,1.81,0,2.171
                c0,0.362,0.133,1.929,0.532,2.051c0.396,0.121,1.193,0.482,1.591,0.964c0.398,0.484,1.061,1.09,1.326,1.69s0.266,1.204,0.266,1.687
                s0,0.965-0.132,1.447c-0.133,0.483-0.267,1.086-0.267,1.086s-0.53-0.48-0.928-0.241c-0.397,0.241-1.46,0.363-1.856,0.724
                c-0.398,0.362-1.99,0.965-2.654,1.324c-0.662,0.365-2.652,1.207-2.652,1.207L20.796,450.1z"></path>
```

```html
<path class="subarea" d="M19.999,389.734c0.397-0.123,1.326,0.121,1.725-0.241c0.397-0.361,1.326-0.967,1.989-1.445
                c0.663-0.483,2.254-2.053,2.254-2.053s1.726-1.085,2.123-1.206s1.857,0.244,1.988,0.604c0.133,0.363,1.726,1.449,2.124,1.809
                c0.397,0.363,1.193,1.088,1.856,1.447c0.664,0.363,1.325,1.327,1.725,1.689c0.397,0.361,1.856,3.255,1.99,3.616
                c0.133,0.362,1.193,2.054,1.325,2.413c0.133,0.361-0.795,1.084-1.062,1.567c-0.264,0.482-0.662,1.687-0.927,2.172
                c-0.267,0.479-0.663,2.171-0.663,2.653c0,0.48-0.397,2.891-0.133,3.494c0.266,0.605,0.53,2.294,0.53,2.775
                c0,0.482,0.266,1.808,0,2.17c-0.265,0.363-0.928,1.086-1.193,1.449c-0.265,0.359-1.193,1.203-1.326,1.566
                c-0.132,0.361-1.725,2.772-1.725,3.254c0,0.485-0.396,2.654,0.134,2.897c0.53,0.239,1.724,0.481,2.52,0.239
                c0.796-0.239,2.653-1.689,2.653-1.085s-0.132,1.927-0.132,2.533c0,0.603,0.132,1.932,0.53,2.411
                c0.397,0.483,0.794,0.845,1.326,1.086c0.53,0.239,1.591,0.725,2.122,0.845c0.53,0.121,2.388,0.48,2.918,0.48
                c0.531,0,1.327,0.12,1.857,0.361c0.531,0.242,1.857,1.09,2.52,1.208c0.664,0.119,1.062,0.481,1.593,0.962
                c0.53,0.484,1.194,1.569,1.857,1.811c0.662,0.239,1.193,0.725,1.724,0.968c0.53,0.238,2.121,0.963,2.52,1.084
                c0.398,0.118,1.593,0.118,2.122,0.118c0.531,0,1.46,0.122,1.725,0.482c0.266,0.364,0.797,1.087,1.061,1.449
                c0.266,0.362,0.53,1.567,0.796,2.29c0.266,0.724,0.53,1.569,0.796,2.412c0.265,0.844,0.265,1.81,0.265,1.81
                s-1.062,0.359-1.591,0.963c-0.53,0.604-1.061,1.086-1.061,1.57c0,0.482-0.133,3.375-0.133,4.099s0.001,3.738-0.133,4.341
                c-0.133,0.605-0.398,1.93-0.664,2.533c-0.264,0.603-0.53,1.447-1.193,1.809c-0.662,0.362-2.919,1.327-3.582,1.811
                c-0.663,0.479-2.387,1.443-2.651,1.929c-0.267,0.482-1.859,2.051-2.123,2.652c-0.266,0.603-1.592,1.688-1.989,2.05
                c-0.397,0.36-2.122,1.447-2.52,1.689c-0.397,0.241-1.062,0.722-1.062,0.722s-0.929-1.566-1.193-2.051
                c-0.265-0.48-1.591-1.686-1.99-2.049c-0.397-0.361-0.928-0.963-1.988-0.963s-3.448,0.36-4.907,0
                c-1.46-0.361-2.652-1.207-2.786-1.93c-0.133-0.724-0.133-3.018-0.133-3.498c0-0.482-0.133-1.688-0.53-2.171
                c-0.398-0.48-1.194-1.447-1.194-1.81c0-0.36,0-2.41,0-2.894c0-0.482-0.53-1.809-0.53-1.809s-0.265,0-0.398-0.362
                c-0.132-0.361,0.398-1.93,0.398-1.93s-0.398-0.965-0.398-1.326c0-0.36-0.662-1.688-0.662-1.688l-0.796-0.846
                c0,0-0.266-0.483-0.663-0.604c-0.398-0.119-1.194-0.239-1.194-0.603c0-0.358-0.396-0.843-0.396-1.205c0-0.361,0-2.051,0.133-2.653
                c0.131-0.603,0.397-1.928,0.397-1.928l0.929-3.86l0.266-1.326c0,0,0.264-1.929,0.264-2.411c0-0.484-0.529-2.294-0.529-2.294
                s-0.53-2.41-0.663-2.893c-0.132-0.482-0.266-0.844-0.398-1.206s-0.795-2.172-0.795-2.172s-0.796-1.326-1.192-1.807
                c-0.399-0.482-1.327-1.448-1.327-1.448s-1.46-0.964-1.99-1.205c-0.53-0.242-1.327-0.968-1.592-1.569
                c-0.266-0.603-0.929-1.809-0.929-2.531c0-0.725,0.266-2.05,0.266-2.05s-0.266-1.329-0.397-1.93
                c-0.133-0.602-1.326-2.051-1.326-2.051l-1.194-1.567l-0.797-0.482c0,0,1.594-1.086,1.858-2.17c0.264-1.086,1.591-4.222,1.724-4.702
                C18.275,395.521,19.999,389.734,19.999,389.734z"></path>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A easy way to do it would be grouping the three paths and using a ``` feMorphology``dilate ``` filter for the group like so:

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:80vh}
path{fill:white;stroke:white;shape-rendering: crispEdges;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "0 370 90 120">
<filter id="outline-red">
<feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" result="expanded"
operator="dilate" radius="1"/>
<feFlood flood-color="red" result="red" />
<feComposite in ="red" in2="expanded" operator="in" />
<feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
</filter>
<g filter="url(#outline-red)">
<path  d="M66.959,395.521c0.397,0,3.182,0.244,3.712,0c0.531-0.24,1.859-0.481,2.257-0.602c0.398-0.119,1.326-1.209,1.592-0.604
                c0.265,0.604,1.459,2.41,1.724,2.893c0.265,0.484,1.99,3.137,2.122,3.619c0.133,0.484,1.991,3.738,2.124,4.342
                c0.131,0.605,0.927,1.328,0.794,1.93s-0.794,1.086-0.794,1.086s-1.726,2.533-2.124,3.014c-0.398,0.482-1.325,1.449-1.459,2.051
                c-0.132,0.602,0,2.049,0,2.653c0,0.604-0.132,1.81-0.398,2.533c-0.265,0.724-0.529,1.445-0.795,1.93
                c-0.266,0.481-1.193,1.085-1.592,1.567c-0.397,0.481-1.193,2.653-1.327,3.376c-0.132,0.725-1.325,4.946-1.325,5.427
                c0,0.481-0.53,3.134-0.53,3.618c0,0.48-0.267,2.292-0.267,2.652c0,0.361-0.662,0.603-1.061,0.723
                c-0.397,0.123-1.327,0.725-1.591,1.086c-0.266,0.362-1.061,1.207-1.593,1.57c-0.53,0.359-2.122,1.082-2.519,1.202
                c-0.398,0.123-0.663-1.202-0.663-1.202s-0.795-3.377-1.061-3.98c-0.266-0.604-0.796-2.051-1.326-2.292
                c-0.531-0.243-1.459-1.206-2.122-1.085c-0.663,0.12-1.99,0.239-2.52,0c-0.531-0.242-1.326-0.485-1.726-0.725
                c-0.397-0.241-1.856-1.086-2.255-1.327c-0.397-0.24-0.796-0.721-1.193-0.965c-0.397-0.241-1.857-1.685-2.389-1.928
                c-0.531-0.241-1.46-0.604-1.46-0.604s-2.387-0.604-2.917-0.604s-1.989-0.48-2.388-0.601c-0.396-0.123-2.255-0.605-2.651-0.845
                c-0.399-0.241-1.196-0.968-1.196-1.447c0-0.482-0.264-1.93-0.264-2.292s0-2.172,0-2.172s2.52-0.844,2.653-1.326
                c0.132-0.48,1.192-1.687,1.592-2.049c0.397-0.361,1.592-0.724,1.857-1.085c0.266-0.362,3.183-2.292,3.581-2.774
                c0.396-0.482,4.509-3.014,4.907-3.256s3.316-2.17,3.715-2.291c0.397-0.121,2.255-1.208,2.52-1.568
                c0.266-0.361,1.724-0.243,2.521-0.724c0.796-0.483,3.316-1.567,3.847-1.81c0.529-0.239,2.52-1.447,2.653-1.809
                c0.133-0.362-0.003-2.531-0.133-3.014C67.356,397.33,66.959,395.521,66.959,395.521z"></path>
  
  
  <path d="M20.796,450.1c-1.061-1.447-2.651-4.824-5.836-11.577c-3.184-6.753-1.062-18.329-3.715-21.708
                c-1.454-1.85-5.645-17.83-2.52-19.725c5.969-3.617,1.193,3.98,5.704,5.736c0,0,1.591,1.62,2.122,2.225
                c0.53,0.602,1.591,2.289,1.724,2.893c0.133,0.604-0.133,2.413-0.133,2.894c0,0.483,0.266,2.051,0.53,2.413s0.929,1.567,1.592,1.93
                c0.663,0.359,2.52,1.205,2.786,1.566c0.265,0.361,1.192,1.326,1.458,1.809c0.267,0.484,1.193,2.413,1.326,2.774
                c0.132,0.362,0.664,1.447,0.664,1.81s0.664,2.776,0.664,3.137c0,0.361,0.264,1.445,0.264,1.928c0,0.481,0.133,1.567-0.133,2.173
                c-0.265,0.601-0.928,2.652-0.928,3.012c0,0.361-0.266,1.569-0.266,2.052c0,0.479-0.399,1.569-0.399,2.049c0,0.482,0,1.81,0,2.171
                c0,0.362,0.133,1.929,0.532,2.051c0.396,0.121,1.193,0.482,1.591,0.964c0.398,0.484,1.061,1.09,1.326,1.69s0.266,1.204,0.266,1.687
                s0,0.965-0.132,1.447c-0.133,0.483-0.267,1.086-0.267,1.086s-0.53-0.48-0.928-0.241c-0.397,0.241-1.46,0.363-1.856,0.724
                c-0.398,0.362-1.99,0.965-2.654,1.324c-0.662,0.365-2.652,1.207-2.652,1.207L20.796,450.1z"></path>
  
  
<path  d="M19.999,389.734c0.397-0.123,1.326,0.121,1.725-0.241c0.397-0.361,1.326-0.967,1.989-1.445
                c0.663-0.483,2.254-2.053,2.254-2.053s1.726-1.085,2.123-1.206s1.857,0.244,1.988,0.604c0.133,0.363,1.726,1.449,2.124,1.809
                c0.397,0.363,1.193,1.088,1.856,1.447c0.664,0.363,1.325,1.327,1.725,1.689c0.397,0.361,1.856,3.255,1.99,3.616
                c0.133,0.362,1.193,2.054,1.325,2.413c0.133,0.361-0.795,1.084-1.062,1.567c-0.264,0.482-0.662,1.687-0.927,2.172
                c-0.267,0.479-0.663,2.171-0.663,2.653c0,0.48-0.397,2.891-0.133,3.494c0.266,0.605,0.53,2.294,0.53,2.775
                c0,0.482,0.266,1.808,0,2.17c-0.265,0.363-0.928,1.086-1.193,1.449c-0.265,0.359-1.193,1.203-1.326,1.566
                c-0.132,0.361-1.725,2.772-1.725,3.254c0,0.485-0.396,2.654,0.134,2.897c0.53,0.239,1.724,0.481,2.52,0.239
                c0.796-0.239,2.653-1.689,2.653-1.085s-0.132,1.927-0.132,2.533c0,0.603,0.132,1.932,0.53,2.411
                c0.397,0.483,0.794,0.845,1.326,1.086c0.53,0.239,1.591,0.725,2.122,0.845c0.53,0.121,2.388,0.48,2.918,0.48
                c0.531,0,1.327,0.12,1.857,0.361c0.531,0.242,1.857,1.09,2.52,1.208c0.664,0.119,1.062,0.481,1.593,0.962
                c0.53,0.484,1.194,1.569,1.857,1.811c0.662,0.239,1.193,0.725,1.724,0.968c0.53,0.238,2.121,0.963,2.52,1.084
                c0.398,0.118,1.593,0.118,2.122,0.118c0.531,0,1.46,0.122,1.725,0.482c0.266,0.364,0.797,1.087,1.061,1.449
                c0.266,0.362,0.53,1.567,0.796,2.29c0.266,0.724,0.53,1.569,0.796,2.412c0.265,0.844,0.265,1.81,0.265,1.81
                s-1.062,0.359-1.591,0.963c-0.53,0.604-1.061,1.086-1.061,1.57c0,0.482-0.133,3.375-0.133,4.099s0.001,3.738-0.133,4.341
                c-0.133,0.605-0.398,1.93-0.664,2.533c-0.264,0.603-0.53,1.447-1.193,1.809c-0.662,0.362-2.919,1.327-3.582,1.811
                c-0.663,0.479-2.387,1.443-2.651,1.929c-0.267,0.482-1.859,2.051-2.123,2.652c-0.266,0.603-1.592,1.688-1.989,2.05
                c-0.397,0.36-2.122,1.447-2.52,1.689c-0.397,0.241-1.062,0.722-1.062,0.722s-0.929-1.566-1.193-2.051
                c-0.265-0.48-1.591-1.686-1.99-2.049c-0.397-0.361-0.928-0.963-1.988-0.963s-3.448,0.36-4.907,0
                c-1.46-0.361-2.652-1.207-2.786-1.93c-0.133-0.724-0.133-3.018-0.133-3.498c0-0.482-0.133-1.688-0.53-2.171
                c-0.398-0.48-1.194-1.447-1.194-1.81c0-0.36,0-2.41,0-2.894c0-0.482-0.53-1.809-0.53-1.809s-0.265,0-0.398-0.362
                c-0.132-0.361,0.398-1.93,0.398-1.93s-0.398-0.965-0.398-1.326c0-0.36-0.662-1.688-0.662-1.688l-0.796-0.846
                c0,0-0.266-0.483-0.663-0.604c-0.398-0.119-1.194-0.239-1.194-0.603c0-0.358-0.396-0.843-0.396-1.205c0-0.361,0-2.051,0.133-2.653
                c0.131-0.603,0.397-1.928,0.397-1.928l0.929-3.86l0.266-1.326c0,0,0.264-1.929,0.264-2.411c0-0.484-0.529-2.294-0.529-2.294
                s-0.53-2.41-0.663-2.893c-0.132-0.482-0.266-0.844-0.398-1.206s-0.795-2.172-0.795-2.172s-0.796-1.326-1.192-1.807
                c-0.399-0.482-1.327-1.448-1.327-1.448s-1.46-0.964-1.99-1.205c-0.53-0.242-1.327-0.968-1.592-1.569
                c-0.266-0.603-0.929-1.809-0.929-2.531c0-0.725,0.266-2.05,0.266-2.05s-0.266-1.329-0.397-1.93
                c-0.133-0.602-1.326-2.051-1.326-2.051l-1.194-1.567l-0.797-0.482c0,0,1.594-1.086,1.858-2.17c0.264-1.086,1.591-4.222,1.724-4.702
                C18.275,395.521,19.999,389.734,19.999,389.734z"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

The OP is commenting:

> Hello. I am sorry if it was unclear, but want to have one path, not more. – Emil E. Ohman

Next comes the combined path. I hope it helps.

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:80vh}
path{fill:none;stroke-linejoin:round}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "0 370 90 120">

<path style="stroke:green; stroke-width:2"  d="M19.999, 389.734 
            C20.396, 389.611 21.325, 389.855 21.724, 389.493 
            C22.121, 389.132 23.050, 388.526 23.713, 388.048 
            C24.376, 387.565 25.967, 385.995 25.967, 385.995 
            C25.967, 385.995 27.693, 384.910 28.090, 384.789 
            C28.487, 384.668 29.947, 385.033 30.078, 385.393 
            C30.211, 385.756 31.804, 386.842 32.202, 387.202 
            C32.599, 387.565 33.395, 388.290 34.058, 388.649 
            C34.722, 389.012 35.383, 389.976 35.783, 390.338 
            C36.180, 390.699 37.639, 393.593 37.773, 393.954 
            C37.906, 394.316 38.966, 396.008 39.098, 396.367 
            C39.231, 396.728 38.303, 397.451 38.036, 397.934 
            C37.772, 398.416 37.374, 399.621 37.109, 400.106 
            C36.842, 400.585 36.446, 402.277 36.446, 402.759 
            C36.446, 403.239 36.049, 405.650 36.313, 406.253 
            C36.579, 406.858 36.843, 408.547 36.843, 409.028 
            C36.843, 409.510 37.109, 410.836 36.843, 411.198 
            C36.578, 411.561 35.915, 412.284 35.650, 412.647 
            C35.385, 413.006 34.457, 413.850 34.324, 414.213 
            C34.192, 414.574 32.599, 416.985 32.599, 417.467 
            C32.599, 417.952 32.203, 420.121 32.733, 420.364 
            C33.263, 420.603 34.457, 420.845 35.253, 420.603 
            C36.049, 420.364 37.906, 418.914 37.906, 419.518
                                               
            C37.778, 419.518 40.298, 418.674 40.431, 418.192 
          C40.563, 417.712 41.623, 416.505 42.023, 416.143 
          C42.420, 415.782 43.615, 415.419 43.880, 415.058 
          C44.146, 414.696 47.063, 412.766 47.461, 412.284 
          C47.857, 411.802 51.970, 409.270 52.368, 409.028 C52.766, 408.786 55.684, 406.858 56.083, 406.737 C56.480, 406.616 58.338, 405.529 58.603, 405.169 C58.869, 404.808 60.327, 404.926 61.124, 404.445 C61.920, 403.962 64.440, 402.878 64.971, 402.635 C65.500, 402.396 67.491, 401.188 67.624, 400.826 C67.757, 400.464 67.621, 398.295 67.491, 397.812 
          C67.356, 397.330 66.959, 395.521 66.959, 395.521                                    
                                               
                                               
                                               
                                               
          C67.356, 395.521 70.141, 395.765 70.671, 395.521 
          C71.202, 395.281 72.530, 395.040 72.928, 394.919 
          C73.326, 394.800 74.254, 393.710 74.520, 394.315 
          C74.785, 394.919 75.979, 396.725 76.244, 397.208 
          C76.509, 397.692 78.234, 400.345 78.366, 400.827 
          C78.499, 401.311 80.357, 404.565 80.490, 405.169 
          C80.621, 405.774 81.417, 406.497 81.284, 407.099 
          C81.151, 407.701 80.490, 408.185 80.490, 408.185 
          C80.490, 408.185 78.764, 410.718 78.366, 411.199 
          C77.968, 411.681 77.041, 412.648 76.907, 413.250 
          C76.775, 413.852 76.907, 415.299 76.907, 415.903 
          C76.907, 416.507 76.775, 417.713 76.509, 418.436 
          C76.244, 419.160 75.980, 419.881 75.714, 420.366 
          C75.448, 420.847 74.521, 421.451 74.122, 421.933 
          C73.725, 422.414 72.929, 424.586 72.795, 425.309 
          C72.663, 426.034 71.470, 430.255 71.470, 430.736 
          C71.470, 431.217 70.940, 433.870 70.940, 434.354 
          C70.940, 434.834 70.673, 436.646 70.673, 437.006 
          C70.673, 437.367 70.011, 437.609 69.612, 437.729 
          C69.215, 437.852 68.285, 438.454 68.021, 438.815 
          C67.755, 439.177 66.960, 440.022 66.428, 440.385 
          C65.898, 440.744 64.306, 441.467 63.909, 441.587
                                               
          C63.506, 441.828 62.444, 442.187 61.915, 442.791 
            C61.385, 443.395 60.854, 443.877 60.854, 444.361 
            C60.854, 444.843 60.721, 447.736 60.721, 448.460 
            C60.721, 449.184 60.722, 452.198 60.588, 452.801 
            C60.455, 453.406 60.190, 454.731 59.924, 455.334 
            C59.660, 455.937 59.394, 456.781 58.731, 457.143 
            C58.069, 457.505 55.812, 458.470 55.149, 458.954 
            C54.486, 459.433 52.762, 460.397 52.498, 460.883 
            C52.231, 461.365 50.639, 462.934 50.375, 463.535 
            C50.109, 464.138 48.783, 465.223 48.386, 465.585 
            C47.989, 465.945 46.264, 467.032 45.866, 467.274 
            C45.469, 467.515 44.804, 467.996 44.804, 467.996 
            C44.804, 467.996 43.875, 466.430 43.611, 465.945 
            C43.346, 465.465 42.020, 464.259 41.621, 463.896 
            C41.224, 463.535 40.693, 462.933 39.633, 462.933 
            C38.573, 462.933 36.185, 463.293 34.726, 462.933 
            C33.266, 462.572 32.074, 461.726 31.940, 461.003 
            C31.807, 460.279 31.807, 457.985 31.807, 457.505 
            C31.807, 457.023 31.674, 455.817 31.277, 455.334 
            C30.879, 454.854 30.083, 453.887 30.083, 453.524 
            C30.083, 453.164 30.083, 451.114 30.083, 450.630 
            C30.083, 450.148 29.553, 448.821 29.553, 448.821 
            C29.553, 448.821 29.288, 448.821 29.155, 448.459 
             
        
          
            C29.016, 448.587 28.486, 448.107 28.088, 448.346 
            C27.691, 448.587 26.628, 448.709 26.232, 449.070 
            C25.834, 449.432 24.242, 450.035 23.578, 450.394 
            C22.916, 450.759 20.926, 451.601 20.926, 451.601 
            C20.883, 451.101 20.839, 450.600 20.796, 450.100
            
            
            C19.735, 448.653 18.145, 445.276 14.960, 438.523 
            C11.776, 431.770 13.898, 420.194 11.245, 416.815 
            C9.791, 414.965 5.600, 398.985 8.725, 397.090 
            C14.694, 393.473 9.918, 401.070 14.429, 402.826 
            
             
            C14.570, 402.874 16.164, 401.788 16.428, 400.704 
            C16.692, 399.618 18.019, 396.482 18.152, 396.002 
            C18.275, 395.521 19.999, 389.734 19.999, 389.734z" />
          
    
</svg>
```

Comment: Hello. I am sorry if it was unclear, but  want to have one path, not more.

Comment: Thank you! I am just curious, how did you do that?

Comment: I transformed all the paths commands (except the `M`) in `C`. Once I had it all in `C` I've removed the parts where the paths were touching and join it all in one path.